# Why do some Vaishnavas not consider Radha as Sati or the Mother of the world & mention Her only as the Hladini shakti?

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism, radha

The well-known pranama mantra of Sri Radha reads

> नवीनां हेमगौरांगीं पूर्णानन्दवतीं सतीम्। 
>  वृषभानुसुतां देवीं वन्दे राधां जगत्प्रसूम्॥
>
> Meaning: I bow down to Goddess Radha, who is young, golden yellow complexioned, full of bliss, a chaste wife (Sati), daughter of Vrishavanu and Mother of the world.

But some Vaishnavas consider her only Hladini Shakti in spite of this widely used Pramana.

My questions are: Why do some Vaishnavas not consider Radha to be Sati or the Mother of the world and mention Her only as the Hladini shakti? Also, could someone mention the source of this pranama mantra which I got in the Puja vidhi book?

Comment: Searching for the source quote and the belief of considering them as mother or supreme are two different and distinct questions. Which Vaishnavas are you referring to? Gaudiya Vaishnavas consider Radha as supreme consort of Krishna. The quote itself says she is mother and you are saying Vaishnavas don't consider. It is unclear now. Please [edit].

Comment: Oh I missed the jagatprasum part ... Sorry :D @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: What is Hlandini Shakti?

Comment: @Lokesh the Shakti which gives pleasure to Sri Krishna and does nothing else